# Casting problems after updating from Swift 4 to 4.1

Tags: alamofire, swift4.1

I've bumped into an odd issue, after updating to Swift 4.1 the cast from JSON to [[Float]] fails. Let me show the code real quick.

```
Alamofire.request(url,
            method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: headers()).responseJSON(queue: queue, completionHandler: { response in
                if let floatDoubleArray = response.result.value as? [[Float]] { 
                    // Do stuff
    }
}
```

The above worked just great in Swift 4.0, but suddenly it fails. The response I get is as follows.

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fb9d02fd800>(
0,
0.05,
0.051,
0.052,
0.051,
0.05,
0.05,
0.049,
0.048,
0.048,
0.047,
0.047,
0.047,
0.046,
0.046,
0.047,
0.047,
0.047,
0.048,
0.048,
0.049,
0.049,
0.05,
0.051,
0.051,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
)
,
<__NSArrayI 0x7fb9d02fde00>(
0,
0.051,
0.051,
0.051,
0.05,
0.05,
0.049,
0.048,
0.048,
0.048,
0.047,
0.047,
0.047,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
)
)
)
```

If I try to hardcast it to [[Float]], I get

> "Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float"

Any ideas how to fix this? It run all fine using Swift 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try

```
if let floatDoubleArray = response.result.value as? [[NSNumber]] { 

   let floatArr = floatDoubleArray.map{$0.map{$0.floatValue}}

}
```

Comment: Yea, it works fine, but I need the data on the form [[Float]]. I really wonder what changed, as I mentioned a lot, it worked just fine in Swift 4.0.

Comment: Works like a charm! Do you have a guess on how the cast suddenly broke?

Comment: I think type casting restrictions added in swift 4.1  as the numeric  value in json is always NSNumber

Comment: How come change log doesn't list anything regarding this? https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#swift-41